# ElasticSearch multimatch query cross_fields type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am trying to use elasticsearch (version 1.0) multimatch query with type set to `cross_fields` like in the manual on elasticsearch page [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields):

the query looks like this (and it's exactly like on elasticsearch page):

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query":      "Robert Smith",
    "type":       "cross_fields",
    "fields":     [ "vorname", "familienname" ],
    "operator":   "and"
  }
}
```

the index is created with jdbc river (with automatic mapping) plugin and working fine with other queries. When I delete the type: `cross_fields` or change it for example to `phrase_prefix` it's working fine. when I change it to the other type like `most_fields` it's not working either. the error I am getting looks like this:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[WXL5tNBeQB6tW0xLDPURRA][df_smsdata][3]: SearchParseException[[df_smsdata][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":\"Robert Smith\",\"type\":\"cross_fields\",\"fields\":[\"vorname\",\"familienname\"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[df_smsdata] **[multi_match] query does not support type cross_fields];** }{[WXL5tNBeQB6tW0xLDPURRA][df_smsdata][2]: SearchParseException[[df_smsdata][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":\"Robert Smith\",\"type\":\"cross_fields\",\"fields\":[\"vorname\",\"familienname\"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[df_smsdata] [multi_match] query does not support type cross_fields]; }{[WXL5tNBeQB6tW0xLDPURRA][df_smsdata][4]: SearchParseException[[df_smsdata][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":\"Robert Smith\",\"type\":\"cross_fields\",\"fields\":[\"vorname\",\"familienname\"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[df_smsdata] [multi_match] query does not support type cross_fields]; }{[WXL5tNBeQB6tW0xLDPURRA][df_smsdata][1]: SearchParseException[[df_smsdata][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":\"Robert Smith\",\"type\":\"cross_fields\",\"fields\":[\"vorname\",\"familienname\"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[df_smsdata] [multi_match] query does not support type cross_fields]; }{[WXL5tNBeQB6tW0xLDPURRA][df_smsdata][0]: SearchParseException[[df_smsdata][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"query\":\"Robert Smith\",\"type\":\"cross_fields\",\"fields\":[\"vorname\",\"familienname\"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[df_smsdata] [multi_match] query does not support type cross_fields]; }]",
  "status": 400
}
```

I can see the parsing exception that query does not support `cross_fields`. is there something I have to set when creating the index?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. Is v1.1 needed for that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linked documentation it says:

types of multi_match query

Note
Added in 1.1.0.

Also mentioned in http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-1-0-released/

You will need to download the newer version.